# Can i scroll a collection view that exists in a collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a need for a `collectionview` that is n `Columns` wide and can be paged by groups of n Columns left and right. Custom layouts will not work for this flow, right?

I can implement the needed behavior just fine using a scroll view in a `collectionview`, but would like the benefits of using `collectionview` cells for the vertical scrolling.

I have not found a way to allow scrolling of a `collectionview` `vertically` in a `collectionview` item that scrolls `horizontally` in a 2nd `collectionview`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created  [this](https://github.com/sanket3003/CollectionViewinCollectionViewItem.git) demo. Check it out and let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks! You definitely proved it can be done.  I tried this same layout, but for some reason, i couldn't interact with anything in the inner cell...scrolling and tapping was disabled on the inner vertical scrolling collection view, but not the horizontal outer one...as if userInteractionEnabled was just off, but it wasn't!  I'll try again :)

Comment: Welcome and I'm sure you can do it :)